# Proving the well ordering principle with induction

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

I am wondering if the following proof of the well ordering principle is correct by induction.

**Well-ordering principle:** Every non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a least or smallest element.

**To prove this, we will prove the following lemma:**

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and let S be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $n\in S$. Then S has a least element.

**Proof by strong induction:**

**Base:** When $n=1$, we have that $1\in S$. Then 1 is the least element of S.

Assume that when $1,2,3,...,k \in S$ then S contains a least element.

**Inductive step:** 
Let $n+1\in S$. This can be broken down into two cases.

**Case 1**: If any of the numbers $1,2,3,...,n\in S$ then S contains a least 
element by the induction hypothesis.

**Case 2**: If S doesn't contain any  of the numbers $1,2,3,...n$ but $n+1\in S$ then $n+1$ is the least element in S.

We have concluded the lemma.

Now using the lemma to prove the well-ordering principle:

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{N}$. This implies $\exists n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\in S$. By the previous lemma, S has a least element.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is essentially how it goes.

Note that what you're doing is really *long induction*, so strictly speaking your induction step should not go from $n$ to $n+1$, but from "all numbers smaller than $n$" to $n$. Or alternatively the claim you prove by induction should be "if $S$ contains some element that is $\le n$, then $S$ has a smallest element".

If you're working in a very formal setting where you have an actual *definition* of $<$ on the natural numbers, and axioms for the concepts that go into that definition, then it would be reasonable for you to go into more detail in case 2 to connect your reasoning rigorously to that definition. But if you *don't* have such a definition, there's not much else you can say but what you're saying already.

Comment: how do we know what induction hypothesi to be taken in this question ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the general idea to be correct but the writing of the proof is slightly confusing to me.

Here is the same proof in my words

Let $A\subset\mathbb{N}$ be a nonempty set.

Let $P(k)$ be the statement that

$$k\in A\implies A\ \text{has smallest element}$$

Let's prove that this is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ using strong induction.

Suppose $1\in A$. Then, for any $x\in A$ we have that $x\geq 1$ since $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Thus, $1$ is the smallest element of $A$

Now assume, as the inductive hypothesis, that $P(k)$ is true for $k=1,2,...,n$.

Assume $n+1\in A$.

Let $k\in \{1,2,...,n\}$.

There are two possible cases.

1. If $k\in A$ then by the inductive hypothesis $A$ has a smallest element.

If $k\notin A$ then for any $x\in A$ we have that $x\geq n+1$.

Thus, $n+1$ is the smallest element of $A$.

In both possible cases, $A$ has a smallest element. That is, $P(n+1)$ is true.

By the principle of strong induction, $P(k)$ is true for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Now, $A$ is by assumption nonempty. Thus, it contains some $x\in\mathbb{N}$.

Then, by the result we proved above using strong induction, $A$ has a smallest element.

Comment: I don't see why "If $k \not \in A$ then for any $x\in A$ we have $x\ge n+1$" is true.  Suppose that $k=2$ and $1\in A$.

Comment: Assume that $n+1\in A$. Assume the inductive hypothesis: for $k=1,2,.\ldots, n$, if $k\in A$ then $A$ has a smallest element. Note that at this point the only element we know to be in $A$ is $n+1$. IF one of $k=1,2\ldots, n$ is in $A$, then by inductive hypothesis $A$ has a smallest element. IF NOT, that is if there is no element $k$ in $A$ with $k=1,2,\ldots, n$, then any element $x$ that is in $A$ must satisfy $x \geq n+1$ because, again, $x$ cannot be one of $1,2,\ldots, n$.