# Is this proof of the well-ordering principle using induction correct?

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, induction, natural-numbers

This question is about proving the well-ordering principle of the natural numbers using the principle of induction. [This other question uses a different induction argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3354376/proving-the-well-ordering-principle-with-induction) than the one below. I'd like to know if the argument below is correct.

Let $A_n\subset \mathbb{N}$ be a set with cardinality $n$, ie $|A_n|=n$.

Let $f_n:\{1,...,n\}\to A_n$ be some bijection.

For any $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $k\leq n$, let $f_k:\{1,...,k\}\to A_k$ be the bijection

$$f_k(n)=f_n(n)\ \ n=1,...,k$$

Note that the image of $f_k$ is $A_k$.

Let $P(k)$ be the property that $A_k$ has a smallest element.

**Proposition:** $P(k)$ is true for $k=1,2,...,n$.

**Proof**

For $k=1$, $A_1$ has a single element which is also its smallest element.

Assume $P(k)$, ie that $A_k$ has a smallest element $a_k$.

Recall that $A_{k+1}$ is the image of $f_{k+1}$ and that this image contains one more element than $A_k$, namely $f_{k+1}(k+1)=f_n(k+1)$.

Thus,

$$A_{k+1}=A_k\cup\{f_{k+1}(k+1)\}$$

If $f_{n}(k+1) < a_k$ then $f_{n}(k+1)$ is the smallest element of $A_{k+1}$. Otherwise, $a_k$ is.

Thus, $P(k+1)$ is true, ie $A_{k+1}$ has a smallest element.

Thus, by induction, we infer that $P(k)$ is true for $k=1,2,...,n$ and in particular this means that $A_n$ has a smallest element. $\blacksquare$

Finally, since $A_n$ was a generic finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ then the above reasoning is true for every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$.

Hence, every finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$ has a smallest element.

Comment: I _think_ the well ordering principle for the integers is that every nonempty subset has a least element. (I haven't read your argument purporting to prove this for finite sets.)

Comment: As Ethan Bolker’s comment suggests, you need to prove every non empty subset has a least element - it is not enough to consider only finite subsets.

Comment: True. Is there a way to make this particular proof strategy work? Or is it doomed?